# How to pan audio in iOS' Web Audio implementation?

Tags: ios, web-audio-api

The WebAudio spec gives API calls for both two-channel L/R panning (StereoPannerNode) and panning in 3D space (PannerNode). Despite this, I can't find an approach that works on iOS.

Regarding normal L/R panning, MDN [says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/createStereoPanner) that the 2D audioContext.createStereoPanner() is not implemented in iOS. (Or on desktop Safari.) Maybe you could create one by directly calling the [PannerNode constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PannerNode/PannerNode), but I'm doubtful that works, at least on iOS.

[AudioContext panning audio of playing media](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20287890/audiocontext-panning-audio-of-playing-media) shows a way to do L/R panning without StereoPannerNode, using channel mergers and channel splitters. However, MDN [says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/createChannelMerger) that createChannelMerger isn't implemented on iOS. Maybe you could directly calling the [ChannelMergeNode constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChannelMergerNode/ChannelMergerNode), but I'm also doubtful that this would work, at least on iOS.

As for panning in 3D, MDN [says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChannelMergerNode/ChannelMergerNode) iOS doesn't support audioContext.createPanner. (Whereas desktop Safari does.) Again, maybe you could use the PannerNode constructor directly, but I'm doubtful. So I don't think 3D panning will work either.

Comment: I haven't tested this because I don't have access to Safari, nor iOS, but have you tried the ScriptProcessorNode (which is now deprecated) route or AudioWorklet (which is not available on iOS, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worklet/addModule )? It seems like you'd have to end up with either a deprecated solution, or some weird two audio files and fading between them.

Answer (score 2):

The `StereoPannerNode` isn't available yet, but the 3D `PannerNode` should work fine (not as constructor yet, but with the `.createPanner()` method). For example this is how you could achieve stereo panning with the 3D panner on iOS:

```js
var pan = -1;  // This should be in range [-1, 1]

if (context.createStereoPanner) {
    var panner = context.createStereoPanner();
    panner.pan.value = pan;
} else {
    var panner = context.createPanner();
    panner.panningModel = 'equalpower';
    panner.setPosition(pan, 0, 1 - Math.abs(pan));
}

someSource.connect(panner);
panner.connect(context.destination);
```

I think that the MDN support tables aren't accurate or outdated a bit. Look in the [PannerNode docs at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PannerNode), the support table looks differently that the ones you've linked.